# Is there any source code analyzer plugin for RAD apart from PMD,CheckStyle & Find Bugs?

Tags: java, plugins, ibm-rad

Is there any source code analyzer plugin for RAD apart from PMD,CheckStyle & Find Bugs ? I'm using RAD 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SonalLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) ? THough this is a new plugin, but works well and is same as SonarQube and runs same rules.

Answer (score 0):

RAD has built in source code analyzer, have you tired it? Go to the `Run > Analysis...`. There are various rule sets define that will analyze your source code. Maybe you will find it sufficient.

Comment: Hi @Gas I have tired that but I need to analyze specific files i.e. 5-6 files at a time and RAD built in source code analyzer doesn't provide that rather it analyze whole workspace.

Comment: @ManthanB You can limit it to certain project or working set, but true no chance to limit to specific files.

Comment: Found out the way to limit to the specific Files. Just Select Files-> Right Click -> Run Software Analyzer.. Now, lets go some deeper...!!! Just Working around If it is possible to analyze specific piece of code from specific file..!!!